# Index is not working on parallel arrays

Tags: c#

The main problem that I am having is that the array variable I am passing into a public method as a parameter from another class doesn't recognize the index location.

PricingApp.cs

```
class PricingApp
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Calls the Display title method
        DisplayTitle();
        // declared the following variables
        string productId;
        int unitQuantity;
        double unitPrice;
        double extendedPrice;
        string loopControl;

        // set loop control equal to "Y"
        loopControl = "Y";

        //Begining of while loop
        while (Convert.ToBoolean(loopControl = "Y"))
        {
            Console.Write("\n\t\tPlease enter the product ID <case sensitive>: ");
            productId = Console.ReadLine();

            Pricing product1 = new Pricing();
            product1.FindPrice(productId[i]);

        }
    }    

    static void DisplayTitle()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\tProject 3 - Pricing Application - Jake Stuck");
        Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t____________________________________________________________");
    }
```

below is the code for the second user defined class Pricing.cs

```
class Pricing
{
    // method for find price
    public static double FindPrice(string id)
    {
        double[] productPrice = { 179.99, 121.99, 46.99, 235.99, 18.99 };
        string[] productID = { "AX3", "SD2", "SD3", "FG5", "PY3" };

        // declared variable for unitPrice
        double unitPrice = -1;

        // Start of for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < productID.Length; i++)
        {
            // if product id matches id
            if (productID[i] == id)
            {
                // sets unit price and product price equal to eachother
                unitPrice = productPrice[i];
            }
        }
        // Return the unit price
        return unitPrice;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn to debug your code. Think deeply what you think `productId[i]` does and what `productId` holds when you call `product1.FindPrice(productId[i]);`

Comment: Try `Pricing.FindPrice(productId)`.  Because its a static method, you do not need an instance. Also, my assumption is you should pass the `productId`, not one character like `productId[i]`

Comment: wow thank you that  worked I've been looking at this for like 2 and a half hours thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't define `i` in `Main()`, so `product1.FindPrice(productId[i]);` won't compile. But you'd define it it wouldn't compile either as the `[]` operator on a string returns the character, of the type `char` at the respective index, e.g. `"Hello"[1]` would evaluate to `'e'`. And there is no method `FindPrice()` with a single `char` argument. So remove the `[i]`.

You might also want to exit the loop in `FindPrice()` once a match was found, unless you expect the products to contain duplicates and want the last match for some reason.

And the two arrays `productPrice` and `productID` aren't that nice either. There is no way to assert they are always of the same length or the corresponding values have the same index. But you rely on that in your loop. Better use a single array of a type that can hold both values, for the id and the price in some properties. You can define your own or at least use some predefined like `Tuple<double, string>` for ad hoc one off things.